# Create new columns which show values based on ranking of other columns python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, partitioning, partition

I have a dataframe with some dates as rows and values in columns. To have an idea the df looks like the below:

```
print(df1)

            c1  c2  c3  c4
12/12/2016  38  10   1   8
12/11/2016  44  12  17  46
12/10/2016  13   6   2   7
12/09/2016   9  16  13  26
```

I want to create a rule such that it ranks each row in df1 and create another dataframe where it stores some constant values. For example to the 2 highest values in each row it assigns the value k = 5 and for the lowest 2 values it shows the value y = -9

What I would like to obtain is the following df:

```
            c1  c2  c3  c4
12/12/2016  5    5  -9  -9
12/11/2016  5  -9   -9   5
12/10/2016  5  -9   -9   5
12/09/2016  -9  5   -9   5
```

I thought about using np.partition on df1 but I am stuck on how to create the new dataframe. Any hints is highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and `DataFrame` contructor:

```
arr = np.where(df.rank(axis=1, method='dense') > 2, 5, -9)

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
            c1  c2  c3  c4
12/12/2016   5   5  -9  -9
12/11/2016   5  -9  -9   5
12/10/2016   5  -9  -9   5
12/09/2016  -9   5  -9   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a NumPy solution:

```
df.iloc[:] = np.where(df.values.argsort(1).argsort(1) > 1, 5, -9)

print(df)

            c1  c2  c3  c4
12/12/2016   5   5  -9  -9
12/11/2016   5  -9  -9   5
12/10/2016   5  -9  -9   5
12/09/2016  -9   5  -9   5
```